# How to display percentages values in stacked bar chart using px.bar()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python

Need to display % sign along with the numeric value. Please check below attached graph. I there any way to add % sign with numeric value?

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['2017/2018', 'Renewable',21], ['2018/2019', 'Renewable',42], ['2019/2020', 'Renewable',75],
       ['2017/2018', 'Non-Renewable',79], ['2018/2019', 'Non-Renewable',58], ['2019/2020', 'Non-Renewable',25]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year', 'Energy','Energy Mix %'])
 
# print dataframe.
df


fig = px.bar(df, x="Year", y="Energy Mix %", color="Energy", title="RENEWABLE ENERGY MIX",
             text_auto=True,template='plotly_dark')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(texttemplate = t.texttemplate + ' %'))
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
# initialize list of lists
data = [['2017/2018', 'Renewable',21], ['2018/2019', 'Renewable',42], ['2019/2020', 'Renewable',75],
       ['2017/2018', 'Non-Renewable',79], ['2018/2019', 'Non-Renewable',58], ['2019/2020', 'Non-Renewable',25]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year', 'Energy','Energy Mix %'])
 
fig = px.bar(df, x="Year", y="Energy Mix %", color="Energy", title="RENEWABLE ENERGY MIX",
             text_auto=True,template='plotly_dark')

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(texttemplate = t.texttemplate + ' %'))

fig.show()
```